# mostrar información de dos tablas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una base de datos de una liga de fútbol, con estas dos tablas (equipos y partidos):

```
create table if not exists equipos (
registro INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
nombre_entrenador VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
nombre_campo_futbol VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
poblacion VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
anio_fundacion INT(4) NOT NULL,
anotaciones BLOB);
create table if not exists partidos (
registro INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_equipo1 INT(2) NOT NULL,
resultado_equipo1 INT(2) NOT NULL,
id_equipo2 INT(2) NOT NULL,
resultado_equipo2 INT(2) NOT NULL);
```

Y necesito hacer esta consulta:

> "Partidos jugados: nombre del equipo1, nombre del equipo2, resultado
>   equipo1, resultado equipo2 ordenados por el nombre del equipo1. Ayuda:
>   es recomendable usar renombramiento de tablas con 3 tablas en el
>   SELECT. (Por ejemplo: FROM EQUIPOS A, EQUIPOS B, PARTIDOS C)."

He escrito esto, pero no me sale lo que quiero y no se como hacerlo:

```
select equipos.nombre,partidos.*
from equipos,partidos    where((equipos.registro=partidos.id_equipo1)or(equipos.registro=partidos.id_equipo1))
order by equipos.nombre;
```

Comment: El enunciado te da una buena pista. Quieres sacar los datos de dos equipos en cada "fila", así que necesitas cruzar los datos de la tabla de equipos **DOS VECES** (una para sacar `equipo1`, otra para sacar `equipo2`).

Comment: Esto también está mal, pero va mejorando:select equipos.nombre,partidos.resultado_equipo1,equipos.nombre,partidos.resultado_equipo2
    from equipos inner join partidos
    on equipos.registro=partidos.id_equipo1
    order by equipos.nombre;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de consultas quedan más claros si usas `JOIN`. Habría que hacer un doble `JOIN` con la tabla `equipos`, dado que en partidos tienes dos referencias a ella, una para cada equipo que se enfrenta.

En cuanto a los alias de tablas, dado que es para abreviar, conviene poner una sola letra, a lo sumo dos o tres letras.

Así debería funcionarte, si tienes los datos correctamente guardados:

```
SELECT
    e1.nombre equipo1,
    p.resultado_equipo1,
    e2.nombre equipo2,
    p.resultado_equipo2
FROM partidos p
    INNER JOIN equipos e1 ON p.id_equipo1=e1.registro
    INNER JOIN equipos e2 ON p.id_equipo2=e2.registro
ORDER BY e1.nombre
```

---

**NOTA:**

Debo decir que en tu diseño quizá convenga una tabla asociativa que sustituya a `partidos`. En ese modelo puede que se haga difícil calcular por ejemplo un total de puntos o resultados de un determinado equipo, debido a que el id de ese equipo estará *bailando* entre dos columnas de la tabla por cada información.

Por ejemplo, si se ofrece sacar el total de resultados que obtuvo el equipo `1` en toda la temporada, vas a tener que leer las columnas `resultado_equipo1` y `resultado_equipo2`y de las columnas `id_equipo1` y `id_equipo2`, buscando el id `1`.

Por ejemplo, si necesitas saber cuántas veces el equipo `5`  jugó como local o como visitante... más de lo mismo.

Puede entonces que tu diseño sea algo deficiente en ese sentido.

También, a las tablas le faltan restricciones. Actualmente nada impide en tu diseño que un equipo se enfrente consigo mismo en `partidos`...

Comment: Muchas gracias @A. Cedano. Con respecto a las ideas que me das en la nota tengo que decir que son buenas, pero estoy en un curso y me dicen que lo debo hacer así.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla de nada. Me alegro de que te haya servido. Si estás en curso no te adelantes, pero lo dejo caer para que lo tengas presente en la vida real, cuando te toque diseñar algún modelo de datos parecido. Saludos.